# "Get intoxicated" vs. "become intoxicated"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs

I was on the Islamic site of Stack Exchange which is currently on beta. We are preparing the website for new users, and one of the moderators and I are confused about some grammar. My answer said "with the insignificant amount of alcohol it is impossible to become intoxicated" and it was edited to "get intoxicated".  Would one be more correct or are they equally correct?

Comment: They are more or less synonymous, but a bit more context would be beneficial.

Answer (score 7):

I think I would prefer *become* in that sentence.

> With the insignificant amount of alcohol it is impossible to become intoxicated.

As I commented, they are practically synonymous, but *get* may have the connotation of a deliberate action for the purpose of intoxication and *become* something more passive. There is an idiomatic phrase "get drunk" which does seem to connote intention; to "become drunk" almost sounds accidental. But that's a subjective view and probably unjustified.

Comment: "Become" covers both the deliberate and accidental route to intoxication, whereas "get" does have an implication of intent. In this case it might depend on content, whether it is a safeguard against people deliberately trying to get drunk, or a safeguard against people accidentally becoming intoxicated.

Comment: Yes, one _gets drunk_ in the pub the night before; up in front of the beak the following day one _became drunk_.

Comment: Also, _become_ is more formal than _get_.

Comment: I would definitely prefer "get". On the other hand, I'm American, and we tend to overuse the word "get".

Comment: he became retired = he got retired according to ginger online grammar chercker

Comment: How unbecoming.