# "to get ubiquitous" or "to become ubiquitous" ...?

Tags: vocabulary

I want to write down a sentence to express the fact that from the 1980's on computers got applied in many facets of our daily lives ... and I am wondering what sentence would be correct:

"As computing got more and more ubiquitous in people's daily lives, ..."

or

"As computing became more and more ubiquitous in people's daily lives, ..."

**EDIT (CONCLUSION):**

Thank you for all the comments!
I have rebuilt the sentence as shown below:

"As computing started to become ubiquitous, affecting more and more aspects of people's daily lives, the demand for reliable programs that are proven to be correct increased"

Comment: both work in speech, but 'got' sounds more informal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is “get” (in the sense of "become/make") appropriate for formal writing](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59735/is-get-in-the-sense-of-become-make-appropriate-for-formal-writing) and [“Get intoxicated” vs. “become intoxicated”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72152/get-intoxicated-vs-become-intoxicated)

Comment: @RegDwighт thank you .. I thought that maybe some usages of get/become depend on the word they are paired with. Thx also for pushing the post you mentioned above ..

Comment: @StoneyB .. is it correct now ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Got* is acceptable in informal discourse, but *became* is to be preferred in formal discourse.

This is not entirely a matter of register, however. *Get* always has a certain overtone of *acquire*, and suggesting that ubiquity is a quality acquired by computers is a little wonky. You'd be more likely to say that computers *got faster* or *got more powerful* than *got more ubiquitous*.

A side issue is whether *ubiquitous* is in fact scalable; I don't particularly object to *more ubiquitous*, since it’s understood as what I would phrase as *more nearly ubiquitous*, but some have a legitimate argument against it. You might avoid the quarrel by writing “As computing came to play a greater and greater role in people’s daily lives ...”

Comment: thank you for this detailed comment .. after re-thinking the sentence I want to write again I followed your suggestion regarding the scalability of "ubiquitous". I've added my conclusion the my original post. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

"As computing became more and more ubiquitous..." is preferable, but ubiquity is better understood as an absolute condition: something is either ubiquitous or it isn't.
How about: "As the use of computers became increasingly common in daily life..."

Answer (score 1):

*Get* is one of those verbs that has many forms and could work in a context like yours the same way *become* does. It seems to be marked informal in formal discourse. So if it's a written and more formal document, *become* will be a better choice and will keep you on the safe side.

Comment: thank you for your comment .. it's indeed in a formal context - it's my master thesis :) and as you an the others suggested I will use "become" ... thx again!

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use *ubiquitous* in a way that is qualified by degree, since it means “everywhere”.  It’s like being more and more unique, or more and more pregnant.

Instead, just say something like:

> As computing became more and more commonplace in people’s daily lives,

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the sentence -

> As computing became ubiquitous, it pervaded every part of people’s daily lives. The demand for...